# Hosting a WCF service in a Windows Service fails

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-services

**Problem**

I have created a simple WCF service. I have already debugged the WCF service separately, it's okay then. I have hosted it in a Windows service. But when I install the Windows service on my computer and try to start it, it can't be started.

I get the following exception:

> Service cannot be started.
>   System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException: HTTP could not register URL http://+:8080/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace. ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied.

I have started my Visual Studio as an administrator and also the Visual Studio Developer command window during the service installation. I have also registered the base address of the service by using the command

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user
```

None of those processes solved the problem. Please suggest how to solve it.

Comment: Try search for some logs in Event Viewer. Maybe disable firewall.

Comment: I have checked logs in Event Viewer, it throughs the above mentioned exception and the firewall is already enabled.